# Will using an Amazon Cognito unauthenticated identity pool ID allow access to my dynamodb outside of Android app?

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

Basically I want my app users to **only** be able to access my DynamoDB tables through the app. Currently, I have an unauthenticated identity pool using Amazon Cognito because the app will not require users to sign in.

I have hardcoded the identity pool id (provided by Amazon Cognito) in my app so I can make read calls to my DynamoDB tables. So is it possible for someone to decompile my app and get this identity pool id, which in turn, they can then make read calls to my database outside of my app? If so, is there a way I can set this up so the only way to access DynamoDB is through the app (without exposing any sensitive credential information)?

I've read through the documentation on Amazon Cognito identity pools but I haven't seen this scenario explained.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible for someone to decompile my app and get this identity pool id

Well, yes it is possible.

The best you can do without major effort is to use obfuscation(e.g. using Proguard). It won't modify your API keys but will scramble your code to make it unreadable for humans.

> Obfuscation: shortens the name of classes and members, which results in reduced DEX file sizes. To learn more, go to the section about [how to obfuscate your code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate).

Referring to [Wikipedia's explanation of obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)):

> In software development, obfuscation is the deliberate act of creating source or machine code that is difficult for humans to understand. Like obfuscation in natural language, it may use needlessly roundabout expressions to compose statements. Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to conceal its purpose (security through obscurity) or its logic or implicit values embedded in it, primarily, in order to prevent tampering, deter reverse engineering ...

So generally speaking, you cannot hide API keys in your end-result APK and be sure it won't be found.

There are tools that decompile APKs and search for anything that looks like API key. [Source](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis)

I can think only of one solution that could give more security: give out only user credentials that are granted on authentication. With these credentials, a user will request data from your server and your server will request data from DynamoDB you referring to. You cannot revoke API keys without consequences, but you can restrict user or device access (depends on implementation) by revoking user authorization token, for example.